# What does the usage of withTx in Groovy do

Tags: java, groovy

Does anyone know what the withTx method in Groovy is for. Does it do something similar to what sql.withTransaction does w/ sql transactions. Tnx.

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: It's not a built-in, so you'll need to show what library it's from. Most likely, it does execute a closure inside a transaction.